# Identical Pandas and SQLite queries not giving same results

Tags: pandas, string, sqlite, group-by, count

I have made a query with the file "Sample - Superstore.csv" from https://github.com/mikemooreviz/superstore that will give me the count for each case that contains some type of criteria for strings, as well as a count without any of the previous criteria for the other counts.

The column with the strings that will be analyzed is "CustomerName".

Basically: count for number of clients where the full name starts with an upper case "A", number of clients where the full name has a lower case "t", number of clients where the full name finishes with a lower case "n", then the number of clients where the full names don't have any of the previous criteria.

This is the query in pandas:

```py
import pandas as pd;import numpy as np;import re;

df = pd.read_csv("path_of_csv_file",sep=";");

pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.width', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None);

df['strings_conditions'] = np.where(
    df['CustomerName'].str.startswith("A"),
    'Starts with a capital A',
    np.where(
        df['CustomerName'].str.contains("t"),
        'Has a non-capitalized t',
        np.where(
            df['CustomerName'].str.endswith("n"),
            'Finishes with a non-capitalized n',
            'Something else'
        )
    )
)

df_new = df.loc[:,['strings_conditions','CustomerName']].drop_duplicates().dropna()

df_new.groupby(['strings_conditions'])['strings_conditions'].count()
```

which gives the following results:

| strings_conditions | count |
| --- | --- |
| Finishes with a non-capitalized n | 100 |
| Has a non-capitalized t | 288 |
| Something else | 341 |
| Starts with a capital A | 64 |

but the same query in SQLite:

```sql
SELECT 'Finishes with a non-capitalized n' AS strings_conditions, count(*) 
FROM (
    SELECT CustomerName
    FROM mag_correction
    WHERE mag_correction.CustomerName glob "*n"
    GROUP by CustomerName
)

UNION ALL

SELECT 'Has a non-capitalized t' AS strings_conditions, count(*) 
FROM (
    SELECT CustomerName
    FROM mag_correction
    WHERE mag_correction.CustomerName glob "*t*"
    GROUP by CustomerName
)

UNION ALL

SELECT 'Something else' AS strings_conditions, count(*) 
FROM (
    SELECT CustomerName
    FROM mag_correction
    WHERE mag_correction.CustomerName NOT glob "A*"
    AND mag_correction.CustomerName NOT glob "*t*"
    AND mag_correction.CustomerName NOT glob "*n"
    GROUP by CustomerName
)

UNION ALL

SELECT 'Starts with a capital A' AS strings_conditions, count(*) 
FROM (
    SELECT CustomerName
    FROM mag_correction
    WHERE mag_correction.CustomerName glob "A*"
    GROUP by CustomerName
)
```

gives me:

| strings_conditions | count |
| --- | --- |
| Finishes with a non-capitalized n | 187 |
| Has a non-capitalized t | 313 |
| Something else | 341 |
| Starts with a capital A | 64 |

And creating a view in SQLite exactly like df_new in pandas with the following query:

```sql
SELECT
    CASE 
       WHEN CustomerName glob "*n" 
       THEN "Finishes with a non-capitalized n" 

       WHEN CustomerName glob "*t*" 
       THEN "Has a non-capitalized t" 

       WHEN CustomerName NOT glob "A*"
        AND CustomerName NOT glob "*t*"
        AND CustomerName NOT glob "*n"
       THEN "Something else"

       WHEN CustomerName glob "A*"
       THEN "Starts with a capital A" 
    END strings_conditions
  , CustomerName
FROM mag_correction
GROUP by CustomerName
```

Then querying it:

```
SELECT df_new.strings_conditions, count(*)
FROM df_new
GROUP by df_new.strings_conditions
```

gives once again a bunch of different results (except for two rows compared to the other SQLite query):

| strings_conditions | count |
| --- | --- |
| Finishes with a non-capitalized n | 187 |
| Has a non-capitalized t | 234 |
| Something else | 341 |
| Starts with a capital A | 31 |

Would anybody know why the results aren't the same in all 3 cases?

If any clarification is needed, I'll happily provide more.

Answer (score 1):

The pandas line `df['strings_conditions'] = ....` will assign exactly one condition to each dataframe row, the same condition when the name is encountered again. The view has the same issue: one "strings_condition" per name. (The numbers are different because the tests are in a different order then the np.wheres).

The "UNION" sql scans the table multiple times, so a given name will be counted in *each* condition it meets.

E.g the name "Art Furguson" meets all three criteria, but the value df["strings_condition"] will be "Starts with capital A"; df_new.strings_condition will be "Finishes with a non-capitalized n".

That is why the results are not the same in all three cases.

Comment: Sorry for the really late reply. I tried your solution and it worked. I will go through the explanations you gave. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the pandas code and SQL queries are not identical for following reasons:

- **Lack of Mutual Exclusivity**: Your conditions are not mutually exclusive. In pandas, you do not count overlapping instances but first matched condition. In first SQL query, you do count overlap since you separate each of the four conditions into scoped `SELECT` queries (i.e., four subsets) for counting.
- **First Match Precedence**: In pandas, `np.where` returns the *first* match in order of logical conditions for overlapping instances. Similarly, SQL's `CASE` takes first match by order. Had you aligned the same order in pandas and second query, results should be similar.

For pandas code to identically match first SQL query, you would need `pandas.concat` + `drop_duplicates()` to replicate SQL's `UNION ALL`:

```py
cond1 = df['CustomerName'].str.startswith("A")
cond2 = df['CustomerName'].str.contains("t")
cond3 = df['CustomerName'].str.endswith("n")

# CONCATENATE FOUR SUBSETS
union_df = (pd.concat([
    df[cond1].assign(strings_conditions="Starts with a capital A"),
    df[cond2].assign(strings_conditions="Has a non-capitalized t"),
    df[cond3].assign(strings_conditions="Finishes with a non-capitalized n"),
    df[(cond1 == False) &
       (cond2 == False) & 
       (cond3 == False)].assign(strings_conditions="Something else")
]).reindex(['strings_conditions','CustomerName'], axis="columns")
  .drop_duplicates().dropna()
)

agg = union_df.groupby(['strings_conditions'])['strings_conditions'].count() 

agg
#                   strings_conditions  count
# 0  Finishes with a non-capitalized n    187
# 1            Has a non-capitalized t    313
# 2                     Something else    341
# 3            Starts with a capital A     64
```

For pandas code to match second SQL query, adjust order of `CASE` conditions. But as mentioned, below undercounts true instances due to overlap.

```py
import sqlite3
...

db = sqlite3.connect("/path/to/database.db")

sql = """WITH sub AS (
   SELECT CASE 
             WHEN CustomerName glob "A*"               -- MOVED FROM LAST TO FIRST
             THEN "Starts with a capital A" 

             WHEN CustomerName glob "*t*"              -- STAYED AS SECOND
             THEN "Has a non-capitalized t" 

             WHEN CustomerName glob "*n"               -- MOVED FROM FIRST TO THIRD
             THEN "Finishes with a non-capitalized n" 

             WHEN CustomerName NOT glob "A*"           -- MOVED TO LAST
              AND CustomerName NOT glob "*t*" 
              AND CustomerName NOT glob "*n" 
             THEN "Something else" 
          END strings_conditions
        , CustomerName

   FROM mag_correction 
   GROUP by CustomerName
)

SELECT strings_conditions
     , COUNT(*) AS count
FROM sub
GROUP by strings_conditions"""

agg_db = pd.read_sql(sql, db)

agg_db
#                   strings_conditions  count
# 0  Finishes with a non-capitalized n    100
# 1            Has a non-capitalized t    288
# 2                     Something else    341
# 3            Starts with a capital A     64
```